# Getting error “Only bindings and etag fields may be set” on using “gsutil iam set”

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gsutil

$ gsutil iam get gs://.../Untitled.html > i.txt

$ gsutil iam set i.txt gs://.../Untitled.html

BadRequestException: 400 Only bindings and etag fields may be set.

Where is the mistake?

Comment: What are the contents of `i.txt`?

Comment: {
  "bindings": [
    {
      "members": [
        "projectViewer:upbeat-sunup-2505"
      ], 
      "role": "roles/storage.legacyObjectReader"
    }, 
    {
      "members": [
        "projectOwner:upbeat-sunup-2505", 
        "projectEditor:upbeat-sunup-2505", 
        "serviceAccount:32731-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
      ], 
      "role": "roles/storage.legacyObjectOwner"
    }
  ], 
  "etag": "CAE="
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue, [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/pull/884) it's the process on how they are working on the solution, your code actually is right.